# Major visual issue with cycles rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Im rendering a scene using cycles which looks absolutely perfect when rendering in view port mode as you can see in the first image[image] 
But when I finally render it, it looks like this[image]
I'm using 2.79 and i tried it on 2.78 with the same result.
any help is appreciated.comment below if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue,

most of the objects had suddenly had invisibility checked, uncheck these and it will appear fine